# Tracing javascript's event with chrome console

Tags: javascript, events, google-chrome, console

Is it possible to track each steps of different javascript events in my Chrome console : because I thought to use it tracing a click event with the 'event listener breakpoints' but it doesn't work (it traces only my jquery files)

Best

Answer (score -1):

you can track any event with a simple Javascript snippet:

```
$(document).live('blur change click dblclick error focus focusin focusout hover keydown keypress keyup load mousedown mouseenter mouseleave mousemove mouseout mouseover mouseup resize scroll select submit', function(event){
  console.log(event);
});
```

Of course, you can change your selector or the list of events.

Comment: Non I want to know which part of the java script code is used